# Transloadit: unable to generate the right signature with ruby

Tags: ruby, transloadit

I tried the example at https://transloadit.com/docs/api-docs#auth-example.

```
p = JSON.generate({ auth: { expires: "2010/10/19 09:01:20+00:00", key: "2b0c45611f6440dfb64611e872ec3211"}, steps: { encode: { robot: "/video/encode" } } })
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'), "d805593620e689465d7da6b8caf2ac7384fdb7e9", p)
```

The result is `00320965b86d42b6d983d1fad3f126ee7385b962`

But according to the documentation it should be `6032b7b62879829941b84df5cfaebfe4644ab4e3`

The Ruby code is borrowed from https://transloadit.com/docs/api-docs#authentication-implementations
and seems to be the same at https://github.com/transloadit/ruby-sdk/blob/master/lib/transloadit/request.rb#L200

PS: Since I only need the signature logic I do not want to use the Transloadit Ruby or Rails SDK.

I use Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1

Answer (score 0):

So there was an issue in the Transloadit documentation that is now fixed and I messed up with the parameters order.

For more information see https://github.com/transloadit/ruby-sdk/issues/21